# PHP Decrypt with special characters

Tags: php, encryption

I tried to decrypt a string that had been successfully encrypted but the string is not displayed correctly as original. I'm using codeigniter.

Example string to encrypt

```
$send_param = "sUserID=A1234&sReference=1003AB";
```

Result the encryption

```
ai1nFLjRDiyZvognuWe0y%2bhakXxaIydp2DUptUfJXL4NKi2chyhE8tZRTKMlPnslL6Gx7TxsR9%2bLwRmWTpd6FROOzD/rfZb70WTMAip
```

Result after i tried decrypt

[image]

Function to Encrypt

```
function encrypt($string_to_encrypt)
{
    return $this->encryptRJ256($this->key,$this->iv,$string_to_encrypt);
}

function encryptRJ256($key,$iv,$string_to_encrypt)
{
    $rtn = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $string_to_encrypt, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    $rtn = base64_encode($rtn);

    return($rtn);
}
```

Function to Decrypt

```
function decrypt($string_to_encrypt)
{
    return $this->decryptRJ256($this->key,$this->iv,$string_to_encrypt);
}

function decryptRJ256($key,$iv,$string_to_decrypt)
{
    $string_to_decrypt = str_replace(" ", "+", $string_to_decrypt);
    $string_to_decrypt = base64_decode($string_to_decrypt);

    $rtn = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $string_to_decrypt, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    $rtn = rtrim($rtn, "\4");

    return($rtn);
}
```

Comment: mcrypt is abandonware. You shouldn't be using it in new code

Comment: Perhaps you need to show how you're using it, because `$string_to_decrypt = str_replace(" ", "+", $string_to_decrypt);` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Please post a _complete_ set of test data. Plaintext and ciphertext without used key and IV do not allow a repro. Also, the base64 encoded ciphertext seems to be _partially_ url encoded. E.g. _+_ is represented by _%2b_, but _/_ not by _%2f_, which can't be solely explained by the code of `encryptRJ256`.